# Where does PCmanFM mount samba devices

Tags: mount, samba, pcmanfm

I discovered that PCmanFM mounts physic devices on /run/media/$USER/, but it seems that it don't mount samba devices in the same directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that PCmanFM mounts samba shared devices in /run/user/userid/gvfs